# 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON object and I have been trying to convert it to a datatype, Say MessageData in C# but I keep getting the error that says

> The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)' has some invalid arguments.

The JSON is as follows:

```
 {
 {
        "SMSMessageData": {
        "Message": "Sent to 1/1 Total Cost: NGN 4.4000",
        "Recipients": [
          {
            "statusCode": 102,
            "number": "+2348033776502",
            "cost": "NGN 4.4000",
            "status": "Success",
            "messageId": "ATXid_b96d58d359d2e12ad0b9696cee7630ce"
          }
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

MessageResponse is as follows below

```
public class MessageResponse
{
    public List<SMSMessageData> Data { get; set; }
}
public class SMSMessageData
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<SMSRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}

public class SMSRecipient
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am trying to deserialize it

```
var response= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageResponse>(json)
```

From the comments, it seems the problem is from the extra enclosing curly braces which I have not found a way to remove so far.
I am not able to do json.ToString() and without converting it to string, I am not able to  apply Trim or any other String methods to remove the extra enclosing curly braces.

Please I need assistance on how to successfully convert this to the MessageResponse data.

I am running it on ASP.Net Core 3.1

Thank you

Comment: A little more info is needed to help with this... whats the command you use to deserialize? Can you post a snippet of json

Comment: the issue is not in the model code, it is in how you're calling Json.Net; can you please include that code?

Comment: can you confirm if this is the json you are using? If so, you need to remove the extra curly braces from start and end

Comment: Where are you getting the json from... what's the method u use

Comment: This is not valid JSON, please verify that you have indeed posted the right input in your question, and if you have, there's your problem.

Comment: @Jawad It is a response from an API call. I don't know what method was used to generate the Json

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That is the json response I have and it is not within my control to modify the API code. That is why I am looking for a way to modify it from my end

Comment: Did you follow my instructions and remove the curly brackets using TrimStart and End? Kindly reply and show your progress 

Comment: How did you call the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,your model is not correct,it should be:

```
 public class MessageResponse
{
    public SMSMessageData SMSMessageData { get; set; } //change this...
}
public class SMSMessageData
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<SMSRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}

public class SMSRecipient
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

For easy testing,the api I designed like below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");//in test.json is your json string
        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

Call the api:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44331/api/values");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    json = json.Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageResponse>(json);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is elaborate

Answer (score 4):

According to https://json2csharp.com/ your JSON is malformatted, I can see you need to remove the extra 2 surrounding curly brackets.

If the JSON comes from an API response you could trim the brackets with a string operation before deserializing, eg

```
var myJsonResponse = json.ToString().Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
```

This is the correct JSON:

```
{
        "SMSMessageData": {
        "Message": "Sent to 1/1 Total Cost: NGN 4.4000",
        "Recipients": [
          {
            "statusCode": 102,
            "number": "+2348033776502",
            "cost": "NGN 4.4000",
            "status": "Success",
            "messageId": "ATXid_b96d58d359d2e12ad0b9696cee7630ce"
          }
        ]
    }
 }
```

The Object Model to represent the JSON:

```
public class Recipient    {
    public int statusCode { get; set; } 
    public string number { get; set; } 
    public string cost { get; set; } 
    public string status { get; set; } 
    public string messageId { get; set; } 

}

public class SMSMessageData    {
    public string Message { get; set; } 
    public List<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; } 

}

public class Root    {
    public SMSMessageData SMSMessageData { get; set; } 

}
```

Then calling it:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse)
```

Comment: Please how would I be able to remove the extra curly braces from the JSON? It comes from an API response

Comment: When I tried to clean up the json,I got this response
"Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Trim'"

Comment: So, as it stands now, I have not found a way to remove those extra enclosing curly braces.

Comment: Convert the JSON to a string and remove them yourself...